# PDO MySQL and php like statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I execute this query to the DB:

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE `date_time_from` like '%0000%'
```

I get a few results, now I am trying to do the same with PDO and I can not manage to get any results or errors. This is what I have done:

```
$dbChain = 'mysql:host='.$GLOBALS['dbhost'].';dbname='.$GLOBALS['dbname'];    
try{
        $dbh = new PDO($dbChain, $GLOBALS['dbuser'], $GLOBALS['dbpassword']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM task"
                . "WHERE date_time_from like CONCAT('%', :dateFrom, '%')";
        $a = '0000';
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':dateFrom', $a);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->rowCount();
        echo $total;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            var_dump($row);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Error'.$e->getMessage();
    }
```

The result of this is `$total = 0`. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

I have also tried this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task"
        . "WHERE date_time_from like :dateFrom";
$a = "%0000%";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':dateFrom', $a);
$stmt->execute();
```

Same result for `$total`.

Comment: What datatype is your column?

Comment: `date_time_from` is a `datetime`

Comment: you do need a space between `task` and 
                . `WHERE` in your query

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking at this code for 3 hours with no clue about what was wrong. Why is it that I do not get an error?

Comment: OK, no problem, I will research about it on my own.

Comment: It does not make a difference in this case, same result no error.

Comment: To enable the expection mechanism use `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` directly after the `new PDO....` line. btw: php can handle mulitline string literals; there's no need for a concatenation in your sql query literal.

Answer (score 1):

bindParam escapes the "%" in the query. It will not work as you expect...

You can, however, use bindValue like so...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE date_time_from LIKE ?";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue( 1, "%0000%" );
$stmt->execute();
```

Alternatively, if you want 0 values from a datetime column, you can just do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE date_time_from = '0000-00-00'";
```